# How to avoid this NullPointerException

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, nullpointerexception, double-buffering

I'm working on a small arcade video game, and I am looking to double buffer to improve animation. I have one class that's supposed to draw the blank image, and another class that's supposed to draw a simple line. However, I keep getting a NullPointerException on the line where the line is supposed to be drawn

```
class Render extends JPanel {
    public int dbWidth = 500, dbHeight = 400;
    public Image dbImage = null;
    public Graphics dbg;

    public void gameRender() {

        if( dbImage == null )  
            dbImage = createImage( dbWidth, dbHeight );

        dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
        dbg.setColor( Color.white );
        dbg.fillRect( 0, 0, dbWidth, dbHeight );
    }
}

class MC extends Render {
    public Render render = new Render();

    public void draw() {
        render.gameRender();
        dbg.drawLine( 100, 100, 200, 200 ); // line where NullPointerException occurs
    }
}
```

I suppose it's the Graphics variable dbg that's null, but it gets the value of `dbImage.getGraphics();` in `gameRender();` How could I fix this NullPointerException?

I am also calling the draw() method in another class like this

```
    public void run() {

    running = true;

    while( running ) {

        mc.draw();
        try {
            Thread.sleep( 50 );
        }
        catch( Exception e ) {}
    }
}
```

I said in that class's constructor that mc = new MC();

Answer (score 6):

You're calling `dbg` on the `this` instance, not the instance of `render`.

You need to change it to

```
render.dbg.drawLine(....)
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to leave the `dbg` call the same, you could call

```
this.gameRender();
```

first and then call

```
dbg.drawLine(...);
```

Answer (score 3):

You setup `dbg` by invoking `gameRender` on `render`, but not `this`.

Answer (score 1):

Since MC extends render, the `dbg` you are referring to belongs to the MC instance that called draw.  You can fix it by calling

```
render.dbg.drawLine( 100, 100, 200, 200 );
```

or take advantage of the inheritance you implemented

```
class MC extends Render {
    //MC is a render, so you don't need to create another one
    public void draw() {
        gameRender(); //Call the MC's own gameRender
        dbg.drawLine( 100, 100, 200, 200 );  //Calling gameRender initialized dbg so you won't get a NullPointerException
    }
}
```